# Java equivalent of Javascript code : sending to WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, socket.io

I need to write java socket emit code for the following javascript code.

```
 socket.emit('pageload', { "inputtoken": $('#wtokens').val() });
```

Java equivalent tried, does not works.

```
productSocket.emit("pageload","inputtoken : 11721");
```

Tried different options, but it does not return any event from the server socket.

Comment: The equivalent would be to send a dictionary, wouldn't it? `{ inputtoken : 11721 }`

Comment: yes, you are correct. dictionary or may be a JSON string. I will give it a try in some time.

Comment: it is a dictionary, javascript is magical !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[blindy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108796/blindy) The following code worked, thanks

```
     Map<String, String>
                     map = Collections
                     .singletonMap("inputtoken", "11721");

   productSocket.emit("pageload",map);
```